# SELECT data with WHERE 2 condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

t_msg

```
msg_id | message | user_id
```

example data :

```
01 | hai how are you | 01
02 | will you marry me ? | 02
```

t_users
example data :

```
uid | username | full_name
01 | greg | Greg Fish
02 | drown | Leon Drown
```

t_friendship
example data :

```
uid | uid_fk | status
01 | 02 | friend
02 | 01 | friend
```

I have 3 tables relations. Now I want message from user show and from other user if status friend.
Example if uid 1 logged in:
uid 1

hai how are you

uid 2 (this show because uid 1 and uid 2 are friend.

will you marry me ?

and this is the query that I made :

```
$query = mysql_query("
        SELECT 
        M.msg_id, 
        M.uid_fk, 
        M.message, 
        M.created,
        U.full_name, 
        U.profile_pic, 
        U.username,
        U.uid, 
        F.status, 
        F.uid 

        FROM
        t_haps_wall M,
        t_users U, 
        t_join_user F 

        WHERE
        M.uid_fk=U.uid
```

Comment: For a matrimonial database? :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to `JOIN` the three tables, with `ON f.uid_fk = u.uid` with the thread table, like so:

```
SELECT 
  M.msg_id, 
  M.uid_fk, 
  M.message, 
  M.created,
  U.full_name, 
  U.profile_pic, 
  U.username,
  U.uid, 
  F.status, 
  F.uid 
FROM t_haps_wall M
INNER JOIN t_users U ON m.user_id = u.uid
INNER JOIN t_join_user F ON f.uid_fk = u.uid
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60d99/4)

Comment: I hate joins, while they work much better than individual queries, they do create dependancies (the query no longer requires just one table but also needs to understand the structure of other tables) hence why it makes sharding harder and queries more complex.

Comment: @VBAssassin, They are not complex compared to alternative solutions, in case of straightforward joins like this question. Try to write the same query without join.

Comment: Na, i know there isn't much alternative here regarding less complexity, but i still hate joins... just like how useful regex is ;)